Game theory: are all moves created equal?
This is a question about a 2-player, perfect-information, win/loss game (like chess, treating draws as Black wins). When both players know the optimal move tree, the outcome is fixed if they play top moves. But in practical play, certain moves can still be more useful, based on psychological or tactical reasons rather than strict optimality.
The Question: In a losing position, what is the best practical defense ?
Most engines rank moves based on distance to mate (DTM), assuming longer paths are better. But some long paths are easier for opponents to find, while shorter paths may actually be harder.

Contextual Factors in Move Selection

Human Factors: Against a human, complex or ambiguous moves can increase the chance of opponent mistakes. Moves could be evaluated by both theoretical merit and likelihood of causing difficulty.

Optimal and Exploitative Play Combined: This approach balances the theoretically best defensive move (like DTM or centipawns) with moves that make practical play harder for the opponent. These moves may not worsen the result but increase the chance for opponent errors, mixing optimality with exploitative strategy.



Thoughts on a Mathematical Approach
Define an evaluation function $f(x)$ for a position $x$ and legal moves $x_1, \dots, x_n$ to select the most practical move in a losing scenario. This could depend on the opponent’s skill level (e.g., ELO rating) and play style.
Some ideas to construct $f(x)$

Blunder Probability: Rank each move $x_i$ by the estimated likelihood of opponent error, using data on human mistakes in complex positions.

Entropy Metrics:



Depth of Threat: Number of moves an opponent must calculate for a winning line.
Branching Factor: Moves with many legal responses could demand more thought.
Position Stability: Moves with large evaluation swings depending on the opponent’s response may add uncertainty.


Adjusted Evaluation:

Here is the best candidate I could come up with:
$$
f(x_i) = e(x_i) + \alpha \cdot p(x_i) \cdot \Delta(x_i)
$$
where $e(x_i)$ is the raw evaluation, $p(x_i)$ the blunder probability, $\Delta(x_i)$ the evaluation swing if misplayed, and $\alpha$ a weight for exploitative value.
Here is where I am stuck, I do not know how to keep all the information I want into a single number, it might be worth treating $f$ as a vector function… any suggestion would be appreciated!

Example from Carlsen-Nepomniachtchi, Game 6 (2021)

In this position, White’s move Kh3 is theoretically drawn if Black replies with Qb1! But Black missed Qb1, and White was suddenly winning.
Note that the computer top move is not the one played by Carlsen, as he was pushing for the win.

Any insights or mathematical approaches to refining this evaluation would be highly appreciated!
